# Can Windows Hibernate be disabled inside a virtual machine?

Tags: windows, virtual-machine, hibernate, parallels

I run [Parallels Desktop](http://www.parallels.com/downloads/desktop/) on my MacBook Pro to host Windows based virtual machines.  I am trying to make the virtual disks a small as possible, and ran across this article: [Delete hiberfil.sys by disabling Windows Hibernate function](http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/tr-dojo/delete-hiberfilsys-by-disabling-windows-hibernate-function/)

Because I use the `Virtual Machine - Suspend` feature of Parallels, I think I can save the virtual disk space by disabling this feature.  The `hiberfil.sys` is sized to the RAM size, so it is a significant savings.

The question is if there is a downside to this, or if there is something I am missing with this approach?

Comment: So what's your question? If you are wondering how to turn of hibernate, you've already got the answer on the link you provided.

Answer (score 3):

I don't think there are any downsides of this.
Anyway, it's pointless to hibernate a virtual machine. I think both hibernation and suspend of parallel works by taking a snapshot of the RAM of the virtual machine. And the later solution is much faster. You should definitely use "suspend function of parallel" instead of the hibernation of the guest OS.